# Dropdown not showing category of an article

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building a website with symfony. I'm trying to get a page to show a form with nested objects. An Artikel can have just one category. There are many artikels and many categories.

```
/**
 * Artikel
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="artikel", indexes=
    {@ORM\Index(name="IDX_A4375C338C9B60D8", columns={"idartikeltype"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Artikel
{
....
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 *
 */
private $idartikeltype;

/**
 * @var ArtikelCategory
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ArtikelCategory"
   ,inversedBy="type")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idartikeltype", 
   referencedColumnName="idartikeltype")
 */
private $category;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="idArtikel", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $idartikel;

......
```

My class ArtikelCategory

```
class ArtikelCategory
{
/**
 * @var string
 * /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Artikel", 
mappedBy="category",cascade={ALL})
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="idartikeltype", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $idartikeltype;

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getType()
{
    return $this->type;
}

/**
 * @param string $type
 */
public function setType($type)
{
    $this->type = $type;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getIdartikeltype()
{
    return $this->idartikeltype;
}

/**
 * @param int $idartikeltype
 */
public function setIdartikeltype($idartikeltype)
{
    $this->idartikeltype = $idartikeltype;
}

public function __toString() {

    return $this->getType()
        ;


}


public function __construct(){
    $this->type = new ArrayCollection();
}
}
```

ArtikelType

```
public function buildForm
( FormBuilderInterface $builder , array 
    $options 
        )
        {
           $builder
        ->add ('titel', TextType::class,array('label'=>'Titel'))

        ->add('datum',DateType::class,array('label'=>'Date'))

        ->add('category' , 

  EntityType::class,array
('class'=>\AppBundle\Entity\ArtikelCategory::class,'label'=>'Page',
            'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er){ return $er-
>createQueryBuilder('t')->orderBy('t.type','ASC');}


        ))

        ->add('tekst',CKEditorType::class,array('label'=>'Text'))

        ->add('save',SubmitType::class,array('label'=>'Save item'))
        ;



}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class'=>'AppBundle\Entity\Artikel',));
}
```

InputController

```
$item = $this-> getDoctrine()->getRepository(Artikel::class)->find($id);


    $form = $this->createForm(ArtikelType::class, $item);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form -> isValid())
    {


        $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($item);
        $em->flush();
       return $this->redirectToRoute('input');

    }

    return $this->render('input/input.html.twig', array('form'=>$form->createView(),));
```

Normally the dropdown should show the category of the artikel as in the database but ...

... In my form, the dropdownlist is not showing the category of an artikel and when i persist the artikel, the new category is not saved.

Icant figure this one out! Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mea Culpa,  when i read [Association Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional)  , It got me thinking. Now i know i'm using a Many-to-One Unidirectional association.
The rest was a piece of cake....

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your annotations are not correct. Remove the @ORM\Column annotation on ArtikelCategory::type. Next add a __toString() method that returns a textual presentation of the entity. In the formType remove all the options in the first place. Just use `-->add('category')` Please follow the examples in the [Association Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) chapter of the Doctrine manual exactly as shown only add the @**\ORM** prefix on the annotations.

After your changes update them to the database with

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

and check if the mappings are correct with

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:validate
```